# Prepend data on Table - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use prepend to populate my table. The data shows in the order i like to have it but something isn't right. When i alert(rowindex), it keeps showing only 0 for every new row i add.

But when i use append, the rowindex alert show 0, 1, 2 for the rows on the table respectively.

What could be wrong ?

```js
var newRow = $("<tr>");
var cols = '';
cols += '<td class="col-sm-2 product-name">data[0]/td>';
cols += '<td class="col-sm-2 product-category">data[1]/td>';
cols += '<td class="col-sm-2 product-price">data[2]/td>';

newRow.prepend(cols);
if (keyboard_active == 1) {
  $("table.order-list tbody").prepend(newRow).find('.qty').keyboard({
    usePreview: false,
    layout: 'custom',
    display: {
      'accept': '&#10004;',
      'cancel': '&#10006;'
    },
    customLayout: {
      'normal': ['1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9', '0 {dec} {bksp}', '{clear} {cancel} {accept}']
    },
    restrictInput: true,
    preventPaste: true,
    autoAccept: true,
    css: {
      container: 'center-block dropdown-menu',
      buttonDefault: 'btn btn-default',
      buttonHover: 'btn-primary',
      buttonAction: 'active',
      buttonDisabled: 'disabled'
    },
  });
} else {
  $("table.order-list tbody").prepend(newRow);
}

rowindex = newRow.index();
alert(rowindex);
```

Comment: cols += '<td class="col-sm-2 product-name">data[0]/td>';   have you do cols = "" before?

Comment: Where is `newrow` created? A more complete example of the code is required here.

Comment: You are getting it as 0 becuase you are always adding the new item to the top of the tbody. So the new one will always have the index 0.

Comment: @AdarshMohan, that makes sense. how do i fix that ?

Comment: if you want the length use `$('table.order-list tbody').children().length`

Comment: And if you need the index of the last node, substract the length by 1

Comment: @AdarshMohan can you show by answer ?

Comment: Please see my answer @user14812075

Answer (score 0):

I have added a P tag in which you can see the three counts of which you might be looking for.

Also I have added a button to add new items to the table.

Since I have no idea what `keyboard_active` variable does, I have made that to `0`

The reason why you were getting `0` as the index everytime is that you were prepending the data to the table, which means you are adding the new data to the top, which is always as the index `0`

```js
var addNewColum = function () {
  var newRow = $("<tr>");
  var cols = '';
  cols += '<td class="col-sm-2 product-name">data[0]/td>';
  cols += '<td class="col-sm-2 product-category">data[1]/td>';
  cols += '<td class="col-sm-2 product-price">data[2]/td>';

  newRow.prepend(cols);
  var keyboard_active = 0;
  if (keyboard_active == 1) {
    $("table.order-list tbody").prepend(newRow).find('.qty').keyboard({
      usePreview: false,
      layout: 'custom',
      display: {
        'accept': '&#10004;',
        'cancel': '&#10006;'
      },
      customLayout: {
        'normal': ['1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9', '0 {dec} {bksp}', '{clear} {cancel} {accept}']
      },
      restrictInput: true,
      preventPaste: true,
      autoAccept: true,
      css: {
        container: 'center-block dropdown-menu',
        buttonDefault: 'btn btn-default',
        buttonHover: 'btn-primary',
        buttonAction: 'active',
        buttonDisabled: 'disabled'
      },
    });
  } else {
    $("table.order-list tbody").prepend(newRow);
  }
  $('#p').html([
    'Total nodes : ' + $("table.order-list tbody").children().length,
    'Last node index : ' + ( $("table.order-list tbody").children().length - 1 ),
    'Current node index : ' + newRow.index()
  ].join('<br />'));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onClick="addNewColum()">Add new column to top</button>

<p id="p"></p>

<table class="order-list">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```